# Comparables to Journal of Algebra, Journal of Pure and Applied Algebra

Tags: big-list, journals

It was recently suggested to me to seek comparable, alternative, journals to the above two (I am not interested in discussing why one would want to do so here).  I am wondering if anyone has suggestions of comparable journals to these two, which I rate as middle-of-the-road specialized journals in algebra.

Optimal answers will be names of journals whose likelihood of accepting any given paper, and esteem amongst people in the field, correlates highly with these two; so, they will consequently be specialized in algebra, and of approximately equal caliber.  Also, it would be good if the rigor of the referee process is comparable.

Comment: http://math.rejecta.org/ ? (Were you really expecting a serious response?)

Comment: Sure, why not?  The issue is not that a paper was rejected from either of those journals.

Comment: @Donu They are both Elsevier journals. If you are not aware, there is a boycott of Elsevier being organized. See http://thecostofknowledge.com/

Comment: Adam, OK, that makes more sense.

Comment: Yes I edited that out of my post to avoid unnecessary controversy.

Comment: The answer depends on the content of your paper. I think the question does not contain enough information (and the answers confirm that) and voted to close. 

Comment: @Mark Sapir: I am not sure who your 'your' refers to. Yet, in view of the comments, it is not at all clear that there is a paper of Anonymous to be submitted/published. The question to me seems to *really* be what journals could serve as sort-of alternatives for JA and JPA *in general*.  
 

Comment: Despite having signed up for the Elsevier boycott, I think this question should not be here. It is subjective and argumentative. There are plenty of places online to discuss the boycott and its implications.

Comment: I can think of reasons why this question should not be on MO, but that there is some boycott is not among them. The questions asks for a list of general algebra journals about comparable to JA and JPA. That's it. Yet we could start fleshing out that question http://mathoverflow.net/questions/3512/top-specialized-journals instead or close it too. 

Comment: I think Mark Meckes's suggestion of moving discussion to the Math2.0 Forum is a good one. So while I think the question as stated is OK for MO, it seems that it would get fuller and more informative responses on said forum, and am therefore voting to close (no slight intended to the OP)

Comment: To avoid discussion (perhaps?) I slightly changed my mind and voted to close as *duplicate* of the question I mentioned.  

Comment: While there are discussions related to the question which belong on other sites, I think the question itself is appropriate and there have been good answers showing that good answers are possible, so I voted to reopen.

Comment: I've started a meta thread: http://tea.mathoverflow.net/discussion/1305/comparables-to-journal-of-algebra-journal-of-pure-and-applied-algebra/

Comment: @quid: "your" referred to OP, obviously. When one submits a paper to a journal, one needs to take into account several things, one of the main
things being the editorial board. In that regard, there are obviously no alternatives to either J. Algebra or JPAA because there are no journals with the same editorial boards.  

Comment: Mark, while technically you are right your answer is too trivial to answer the question. The OP is not interested in isomorphism of journals, but in equivalence up to area and level.  

Comment: @Yiftach Barnea: It would add meaning to what you were saying if you understood what you were talking about. 

Comment: @Mark Sapir you might be right. But telling peope they do not understand does not make them understand. You might like to consider explaining yourself better. 

Answer (score 14):

In my opinion the question is somewhat vague. However, I think that Algebra and Representation Theory or Algebra and Number Theory are examples of specialized journals in algebra of level more or less similar to J. Algebra or Journal of Pure and Applied Algebra.

Comment: I have to agree that the question is somewhat vague (or perhaps at least subjective/fuzzy), but I am not sure how to be more precise.  In any case, those answers help.  Thanks!

Comment: Agreed. Algebra and Number Theory seems to have a much better reputation than Journal of Algebra among people I know. (Even if we ignore the publisher matter.)

Comment: The editorial board is indeed very impressive, but there is hardly any group theorist there.   

Answer (score 14):

Communications in Algebra (Taylor and Francis). It was my impression that some years ago it was considered as slightly worse than the ones you mentioned, but I also believe they tried to improve lately.

Journal of Algebra and its Applications (WorldScientific). Most likely also considered as not quite as good, but perhaps not much worse either.

Comment: Thank you for including publishers in your reply, since that seems to be at the heart of this question.

Comment: What is known about the iniquities or virtues of those publishers? I, for instance, have an informal boycott of World Scientific for personal reasons, but would be prepared to accept evidence that they are more of a force for good to the maths community than Elsevier. (If people don't want to discuss this publically, they are welcome to contact me by email.)

Comment: @Yemon: It was not my, and also not OPs it seems, intention to start a discussion of publishers. I merely tried to answer the question as aked.(Hey, perhaps somebody just does not like either green or purple and thus wants a journal with a differen color...CA would be red and JAA white and blue)  [ps. Once I dicided to publish somewhere mainly on the grounds that I liked the color of the journals cover, so this is not absurd, or maybe it is, but not for me ;D]

Comment: @Yemon: are the reasons for your boycott something you want to keep for yourself, or can we get to hear them? I am just being curious - as far as I know, World Scientific is the kind of publishing house which is just as bad as any other, but it does not have the undeserved seriosity nimbus that Springer, T&F etc. have for whatever reasons. Is there something I've missed that makes it even worse?

Comment: Someone will surely come along shortly and point out that discussions like this are ill-suited to MO comment threads and would be better placed on a forum.  Rumor has it that an appropriate forum now exists: http://www.math.ntnu.no/~stacey/Mathforge/Math2.0/

Comment: Discussions like this are ill-suited to MO comment threads and would be better placed on a forum.  It was not my intention to start one here.

Comment: I apologize for derailing the original purpose of the enquiry. Perhaps I should delete my comment?

Answer (score 13):

I think Journal of Algebra is the top journal in algebra (at least in some areas of algebra). But the quality varies. Some papers are excellent and some are just good. In my view Communication in Algebra and Algebra and Representation Theory are decent journals (indeed I have published in both), but I would say they are a level below Journal of Algebra. I am not familiar too much with Journal of Pure and Applied Algebra.

I think Journal of Group Theory is in the level of Journal of Algebra (some say better).

Groups, Geometry and Dynamics seems to publish good papers recently, but it is relatively new so I am not sure about reputation.

I have just recently noticed Journal of Algebra and its Applications and it seems to have a very good editorial board.

Comment: This confirms my motivating concern, being that there is not an ideal alternative at the moment.  Thank you for this helpful answer; I will look into the two you mentioned in addition to Salvo's suggestions.

Comment: This is my view. You might want to hear more people before formaing your view. Actually, I would also be happy to hear what other people think. 

Answer (score 5):

International Journal of Algebra and Computation (IJAC), published by World Scientific, is another possibility. In practice they have their areas of speciality, such as geometric group theory.

Comment: I am not familiar with the journal, but the editorial board is excellent.

Answer (score 4):

The [Journal of Commutative Algebra](http://rmmc.asu.edu/jca/jca.html) is a more specialized journal that I believe tries to be of similar quality to the Journal of Algebra.

In particular, they have recently asked their referees whether they would recommend that this paper would also be accepted at the Journal of Algebra and state that they are shooting for comparable quality.

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean?

Comment: @Karl: I think, he meant "advertisement" (compare "publicite" in French). In this case, the answer is "of course not". 

Comment: Thanks, for clarifying.  I'm not an editor of that journal or anything, although Graham Leuschke (a frequent mathoverflower) is.