# Coarsening arXiv subject tags by journal preferences

Tags: soft-question, arxiv, msc

Sorry if this question is too soft or off-topic, but I wasn't sure where else to get feedback from a broad range of subfields.

**Short version:** How should one condense the 32 existing [arXiv math subject tags](https://arxiv.org/archive/math) into approximately 10 "subject areas"? There can be overlaps between the subject areas, but ideally researchers within a given area would have similar preferences for specialized journals.

**Long version:** After discussing with some other early-career researchers, I'm thinking about putting together a ranking of math journals based on survey responses from established researchers. This would by no means be a definitive ranking, but it would at least allow one to get a sense of "expert opinions" about various journals.

As a feature, I would like to allow one to filter results based on the primary research area(s) of the respondents. However, I do not plan on stipulating how many journals a given respondent should rank, so I will have to use something like Plackett--Luce to generate an overall ranking. The difficulties arise when generating this ranking:

- If I generate this ranking for all possible combinations of arXiv tags, I need to run a Plackett--Luce implementation $2^{32}$ times and store the resulting rankings. That's not going to work, but this approach should be just fine for around $2^{10}$ combinations of subject areas.
- Given a choice of subject areas, I could generate this ranking live. However, the graphical display of the rankings would take a non-user-friendly amount of time to update. Also, the only Plackett--Luce implementatons I've seen are in R, and I really should be getting ready for job applications instead of trying to figure out how to run R on a website.

One option is the classification used in the [AMS annual survey](http://www.ams.org/profession/data/annual-survey/phds-awarded) on "doctoral recipients by field of thesis," but it's not clear to me where e.g. math physics would belong. These categories are:

1. Algebra / Number Theory
2. Real, Complex, Harmonic, and Functional Analysis
3. Geometry / Topology
4. Discrete Math / Combinatorics / Logic / Computer Science
5. Probability
6. Statistics
7. Biostatistics
8. Applied Math
9. Numerical Analysis / Approximations
10. Linear and Nonlinear Optimization / Control
11. Differential, Integral, and Difference Equations
12. Math Education
13. Other

Comment: The AMS division seems verrry weird to me. For instance, breaking probability and statistics into two different groups, but grouping discrete math and logic together?

Comment: Btw, you might be interested in this older MO question: https://mathoverflow.net/questions/3512/top-specialized-journals

Comment: @SamHopkins I agree, but I’m far enough removed from those areas that I didn’t know whether that was just my ignorance.

Comment: And that post on specialized journals was actually the motivation for adding a subject filtering feature.

Comment: @SamHopkins ... In large universities: statistics is often a separate department from math, whereas probability is (a small) part of the math department.

Comment: Conveniently, the NSF Division of Mathematical Sciences has exactly 11 disciplinary research programs. If you exclude statistics (which is often a different department) , that brings it down to 10. https://www.nsf.gov/funding/programs.jsp?org=DMS

Comment: One problem with any attempt to split mathematics into fixed areas is that a reasonably good classification at some time can become awkward 20 years later.

Comment: @WillieWong Thanks, this looks like it should work well!

Comment: @YCor I agree, but I don’t expect any survey of opinions on journals to be valid for 20 years anyway. I have no idea how frequently one would want to update such a survey though

Answer (score 1):

Technical solution to an analytic problem, sounds my style:  The [littler](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/littler/index.html) package, to be read as "little R" is a CLI interface to R, so running R on a website should be as straightforward as a shellout to that.  It's installable as a system package in Debian (and would you run a web-server on anything else?).

Comment: Thanks for the tip! There’s still the issue of the update time when computing the ranking, but this will be very helpful if I need to go this route