# Top journals in mathematical analysis

Tags: real-analysis, ap.analysis-of-pdes, journals

How would you (broadly) rank the journals that specialize in mathematical analysis and related areas such as PDEs?

As far as I know, GAFA looks like it is the top one. But apart from that, how can I compare other "good" analysis journals? I'm more than happy with partial answers!

Some of them:

- Geometric and Functional Analysis
- Archive for Rational Mechanics and Analysis (looks like it was a top journal, I don't know if it continues to be)
- Calculus of Variations and Partial Differential Equations
- Communications in Partial Differential Equations
- Communications on Pure and Applied Mathematics (I'm not sure whether this one is a generalist or not but I only see analysis papers)
- Journal of Differential Equations
- Journal of Functional Analysis
- Analysis & PDE
- Journal de Mathématiques Pures et Appliquées (I guess this is a generalist one, but almost all the published papers I see are analysis or PDE related)

EDIT: First, I add two journals that have been pointed out to me in the comments: SIAM math analysis and Journal d'Analyse Mathematique.
Also, let me change a bit my question: are there big differences in quality among some of the journals I've mentioned? Or they are all roughly the same quality? Again, I'm more than happy with partial answers.

Comment: CPAM and GAFA are equally top-rank journals for analysis

Comment: Isn't PDE part of mathematical analysis (and not just a related area)?

Comment: Add SIAM Math analysis to the list

Comment: Journal d’Analyse Mathématique (Jean Bourgain had 33 papers there).

Comment: Close as "opinion-based"?

Comment: @GerryMyerson It is certainly opinion-based; on the other hand, a [very similar MO question](https://mathoverflow.net/a/179809) has not been closed.

Comment: Let me ask a simpler question, is there a quality gap (in any direction) between  Calc. var and PDE and Analysis and PDE?

Comment: I should mention once more that the level of a journal can undergo significant variations with time. It can also be a top specialized journal in one given subtopic and not in another (the quality of the editorial board can be heterogeneous, and so is the reputation).

Comment: I wonder whether there is a variation of this question that would be accepted by this community (or another adequate community where I can ask this). I think the question is interesting for many people (see how many people has bookmarked the linked question) and it's hard to find an answer without insider knowledge, so I'd be happy to repurpose it.

Comment: As for the last comment: I don't know what kind of questions would be acceptable. Maybe you could raise a question in https://meta.mathoverflow.net/ to ask this — of course, questions of this sort are of interest to mathematicians, but it is unclear what platform is better (MO is more QA, and this might be considered better suited for forums.)

Comment: @jgall: may be you can update the analysis-answer to the linked question based on the inputs you got from comments here? It seems to me in the spirit of that question given it is a community wiki. And, as one of those who bookmarked that question, I would certainly value answers more if they get updated with time.

Comment: @pinaki unfortunately, I can only add that CPAM seems to be a very good journal, comparable to GAFA